# ASIHTTP using block, terminated due to uncaught exception

Tags: ios, ios7, request, asihttprequest, unrecognized-selector

I'm using ASIHTTP in an old iOS 7 project. So today i updated my files to the newets version of ASIHTTP and tried to use a using block as showed in an example on http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use . My code looks like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL To A Site That Returns A JSON String"];
__block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"]; //Returneres som JSON
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

    // Use when fetching binary data
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
}];
[request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSError *error = [request error];
}];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

When running the code i get the following exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ASIHTTPRequest setFailedBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x157529f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2f17bf0b 0x39912ce7 0x2f17f837 0x2f17e137 0x2f0cd098 0x1262fd 0x125957 0x111fcf 0x319afa53 0x319af811 0x31ad758b 0x31ad741f 0x31ad72f7 0xe1c63 0x31ac97f3 0x31b7bcb3 0x31a2ae09 0x319a3b57 0x2f147039 0x2f1449c7 0x2f144d13 0x2f0af769 0x2f0af54b 0x3401c6d3 0x31a0e891 0xb147d 0x39e10ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Note that if i do a Synchronous call it works: but i need this call to be Asynchronous.

Any help fixing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Beaware that ASIHttpRequest is no longer supported by its developers and has know bugs in iOS 6 and higher. IF possible you should use a library for handling netwerkt request.

Comment: hmm ok:(. Got any suggestions?

Comment: There is the popular [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and [`MKNetworkKit`](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit) is not updated in a long time. [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is regularly updated and is a very populiar.

Comment: Ok thx a lot. Ill try out the best looking one:)